# Java boolean parameter changes its value w/o any assignment

Tags: java

today I had a very embarrassing experience.
I just called Push.payload() method like this.

```
Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, token);
```

(In fact, this code snippet is part of javaPNS)
And Push.payload() is just

```
public static PushedNotifications payload(Payload payload, Object keystore, String password, boolean production, Object devices) throws CommunicationException, KeystoreException {
    return sendPayload(payload, keystore, password, production, devices);
}
```

production value was true when I called Push.payload(), and there is no assignment except its declaration.

```
private static final boolean production = true;
```

Of course I checked that its value is true before step in Push.payload() in debug mode. HOWEVER, in Push.payload() method, the production value turns into false!!

I don't know what happened. Please explain why the production value changed to false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "production" variable that you see in Debug Module is the parameter of method "Push.payload()" in fact.
if the name of the static variable is same as the name of parameter in the method. jvm regard it as a parameter of the method in priority.
so, I recommand you user Upper case like 'PRODUCTION'. and you'd better use 
`Xxxxx.PRODUCTION`
this style is better for reading.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It was my fault to remain lower case when I change the variable to 'final'. The production which was passed to Push.payload() was parameter. But dare I say, though the result was my fault, the variable window presented that production value(as a parameter) is true. I think it was eclipse's bug since after restarted eclipse, it shows false in the same code. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

If you call

```
Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, false, token);
```

then the `production` will be false inside the method call.

If this value is a constant, why are you passing it as a parameter?  If you can't remove it I suggest giving it a different name e.g. Use Java Code Convention.

```
private static final boolean PRODUCTION = true;
```

Comment: I used production variable as a switch and the variable used in multiple place. Anyway, it was my mistake to remain lower case when I change it to 'final'. As @Hawk said, it was regarded as a parameter. The result was obviously my own fault, but I think, dare to say, it was bug of eclipse to present that the production value(as a parameter) is true. Thank you for your advice!